# Italian rules on the co-occurrence of directors in competing companies

Tags: competition, antitrust-law, italy

I would like to know whether in Italy there are laws preventing the co-occurrence of directors (executive and/or non-executive) in competing companies.

I'm writing a paper on board interlocks (firms sharing directors) among Italian companies operating in the same industry. I know about articles 2390 and 2391 of the Civil Code and the Law No. 214/2011. Any suggestion on other relevant pieces of legislation would be very welcome.